# CSS resolution optimizing?

Tags: css, optimization, size, resolutions

So i am making a website, and its done exept that window sizing is not very optimized yet. 
I have been using media query for css3 but its not working on all browsers
So im asking, can i do anything with my CSS that makes everything stay at the same size if someone resizes or are using a different resolution?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/Z4EKAdVj

website:
http://www.hyperqube-game.tk

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check mediaqueries.js for IE5+, its working fine, you just have to paste script in site.
https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Then for example IE7 is rendering correct page size to resolution